# Is a line a convex set?

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

I was thinking about whether a $\textbf{line}$ is a convex set.

My intuition is as follows:

> A set is convex if it includes all convex combinations of points in
>   the set. Or in other words, if it contains all line segment joining
>   any two points in the set.

Thus, a line is a convex set.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you right.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, if you want a rigorous proof, you might want to use the definition of convex set: A subset $C$ of a real vector space $X$ is convex if, for every $x \in C$ and $y \in C$ and every $0 < \alpha < 1$, we have $\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y \in C$.

Comment: The point is: Where does the line lies?

Comment: @DiegoMath, I think of a line as a line segment joining the 2 extreme ends, thus delivering it convex as line segments are convex. I understand it is a crude way , but I am just trying to form intuition. And I hope this is right. Thanks :)